# User is unable to receive desktop notification for events

Tags: lightning-experience, notification

How come User is able to get notification from task but unable to receive notification for events?

[image]

User does not have any permission sets or restriction rule regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have the turned them off in their personal settings

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activities_reminder_lex.htm&type=5